# Can FQL be used to extract a list of all applications a user uses?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible, using FQL, to find out which applications a user is using? I have looked at the stream and application tables and am able to get a bit of info from there, but only for updates posted the past 30 or so days. And it also gives me a lot of info that i do not need. So, is it somehow possible to get a list of app ID's, canvas names and descriptions of all (active published) applications a user has subscribed to?

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't a good way to do this.

An app can check if it is installed by a particular user or by a user's friends, but not list all apps used by a user

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint but I think this is impossible.

Facebook applications have no way of accessing the users application list. Your application can however check details of other applications using the open graph, but there is no such query that will return a list of applications installed by a user. This is regardless of being authorized or not. There's no such feature available in Facebook's API.

Your application can of course check if it's installed by any User ID. This is good for checking if the users friends have also installed your application.