# How to get the using apps by user using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get using Facebook apps by Graph API.

But I can't find the docs about it.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if the API will return a list of apps a user has authorised?

I don't believe there's any such API method. - see also [Can FQL be used to extract a list of all applications a user uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589836/can-fql-be-used-to-extract-a-list-of-all-applications-a-user-uses) - it is not possible

Comment: Yes, I want to know those API. Thanks.